# Hiding and Showing Content using CSS3, Want hidden state the be the default

Tags: html, css, focus, show-hide, hidden

I hope someone out there can help. I've been trying for several days to make simple list hide and show when the links "hide" and "show" are on the screen. I found the following online:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>menu mockup</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
 .show {display: none; }
 .hide:focus + .show {display: inline; } /*this is the switch*/
 .hide:focus { display: none; } /*this is the switch*/
 .hide:focus ~ #list { display:none; }*/
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Here's a list</p>
  <div>

     <a href="#" class="hide" tabindex="1">[hide]</a>      
     <a href="#" class="show" tabindex="2">[show]</a>
     <ol id="list">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>

     </ol>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the list to be hidden when you first open the page. Right now the default state is for list to show. I got this code from the following website: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-show-and-hide/

I tried what was suggested in one of the comments in the article to reverse the process to show the list hidden but it doesn't work. Here's that code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>menu mockup</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.hide {display: none; }
.show:focus + .hide {display: inline; }
.show:focus { display: none; }
.show:focus ~ #list { display:none; }
@media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here's a list</p>
<div>

<a href="#" class="show">[hide]</a>
<a href="#" class="hide">[show]</a>
<ol id="list">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ol>
</div>
<p>How about that?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can offer a simple fix to this, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code where i have changed the css as well as position of anchor tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>menu mockup</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
 .hide {display: none; }
 #list {display: none; }
 .show:focus { display: none; }
 .show:focus + .hide {display: inline; }
 .show:focus ~#list{ display:block; }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Here's a list</p>
  <div>

     <a href="#" class="show" tabindex="2">[show]</a>
     <a href="#" class="hide" tabindex="1">[hide]</a>      
     <ol id="list">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
     </ol>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As long as you only want to show and hide a menu, the code works. However, using a tags instead of "item 1" etc. does not. No new page opens; the menu just closes.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `#list` to `display:none` on a line by itself.  This will make the default state hidden.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, #list {display: none;} which does hide the list but then it remains hidden when you click the links. How do I get it to come back?